# querySelector returns 'Failed to execute div is not a valid selector' when it exists in the DOM

Tags: javascript, escaping, queryselector

I'm running into an issue where the 'div ID' isn't valid when I run it from the code.

However, when I `document.querySelector('#div-gpt-ad\\/1594654184865-0>div')` it returns the correct div ID.
Screenshot of error: https://gyazo.com/a7f1898f246bd84f28e85c2052ac60eb

The div id exists on page before executing the code, the console.log in the renderDiv function returns

Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```cs
var slots = window.top.googletag.pubads().getSlots();
 
init(slots);
function init(slots) {
    for (let i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
        renderDiv(slots[i]);
    }
}
function getSelectors(slot) {
    var escapeCheck = slot.getSlotElementId();
    if(escapeCheck.includes('/')){
       let placeHold = escapeCheck.replace(/\//g, '\\\\/');

        return  "#" + placeHold + ">div" ;
    } else{ 
    return "#" + escapeCheck + ">div";
}
}
function renderDiv(slot) {
        let selector = getSelectors(slot);
        
        console.log("Selector:" + selector)
       document.querySelector(selector)

}
```

Comment: Try `console.log('#div-gpt-ad\\/1594654184865-0>div')` and spot the differences with what `console.log("Selector:" + selector)` is logging. Looks like your escaping is going wrong.

Comment: I see, this returns 'undefined' I think this is 1 step closer to where I need to be!

Comment: Nvm, this gives no difference. They're both the same

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

Changed `let placeHold = escapeCheck.replace(/\//g, '\\\\/');`  to

```
let placeHold =escapeCheck.replace(/\//g, "\\/").replace(/\./g, "\\.");
```

Something I quite don't understand yet is why the first one did not work as the string was correct that was passing through

Comment: "_as the string was correct that was passing through_" No it wasn't. In the selector that was working, you passed `\\/`. In your replacement you replaced it with `\\\\/`. That's not the same amount of backslashes.